# Implement gradient descent in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient descent in python. Though my code is returning result by I think results I am getting are completely wrong.

Here is the code I have written:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

dataset = pandas.read_csv('D:\ML Data\house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques\\train.csv')

X = np.empty((0, 1),int)
Y = np.empty((0, 1), int)

for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
  X = np.append(X, dataset.at[i, 'LotArea'])
  Y = np.append(Y, dataset.at[i, 'SalePrice'])

X = np.c_[np.ones(len(X)), X]
Y = Y.reshape(len(Y), 1)

def gradient_descent(X, Y, theta, iterations=100, learningRate=0.000001):
  m = len(X)
  for i in range(iterations):
    prediction = np.dot(X, theta)
    theta = theta - (1/m) * learningRate * (X.T.dot(prediction - Y))

  return theta

  theta = np.random.randn(2,1)
  theta = gradient_descent(X, Y, theta)
  print('theta',theta)
```

The result I get after running this program is:

> theta [[-5.23237458e+228]
>    [-1.04560188e+233]]

Which are very high values. Can someone point out the mistake I have made in implementation.

Also, 2nd problem is I have to set value of learning rate very low (in this case i have set to 0.000001) to work other wise program throws an error.

Please help me in diagnosis the problem.

Comment: Code here : https://github.com/0xPrateek/ML-Algorithms/blob/master/Algorithms/Linear%20Regression/LinearRegression.py is self-explained although it's in component form implementation but will be helpful to understand

Comment: What's the error when you chang learing rate

Comment: @0xPrateek RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract

Comment: @0xPrateek The link you provided is very verbose. I am trying to implement gradient descent using numpy's ability to do vector calculations. That makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: In the line `theta = theta - (1/m) * learningRate * (X.T.dot(prediction - Y))`, `theta` is a 1d vector, but `(1/m) * learningRate * (X.T.dot(prediction - Y))` is a single value. While the operation is valid in numpy, it is meaningless in mathematics.

Comment: @Leporello, actually you are wrong about theta. It's a 2d array.  check yourself using `theta.ndim`. It will give 2. And, `(1/m) * learningRate * (X.T.dot(prediction - Y))` is of shape `(2, 1)` same as `theta`

Comment: your learning rate is too low it would take hours to converge.increase it.

Comment: My bad, I read too fast. (I am still not sure of the math behind the formula - aren't the two components of theta storing the same information, then, given how np.dot operates?)

Comment: @BalkrishanNagpal, try to plot graph between no of iterations and cost. You will be shocked to see the output.

Comment: Did you tried to plot cost versus iteration plot

Comment: Plotting a cost vs iter will give you better insights into your choice of the learning rate, it should be ideally decreasing continuously.

Answer (score 1):

try to reduce the learning rate with iteration otherwise it wont be able to reach the optimal lowest.try this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

dataset = pandas.read_csv('start.csv')

X = np.empty((0, 1),int)
Y = np.empty((0, 1), int)

for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
  X = np.append(X, dataset.at[i, 'R&D Spend'])
  Y = np.append(Y, dataset.at[i, 'Profit'])

X = np.c_[np.ones(len(X)), X]
Y = Y.reshape(len(Y), 1)

def gradient_descent(X, Y, theta, iterations=50, learningRate=0.01):
  m = len(X)
  for i in range(iterations):
    prediction = np.dot(X, theta)
    theta = theta - (1/m) * learningRate * (X.T.dot(prediction - Y))
    learningRate/=10;

  return theta

theta = np.random.randn(2,1)
theta = gradient_descent(X, Y, theta)
print('theta',theta)
```